# Login into 2 accounts of one website at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, account, user-accounts

I need this function in my app because I have accounts in gmail both for home and office work.

I know how to send web-requests and receive answers. So I can login into one account. But what to do if there several my accounts on one website?

Someone said that it is possible on PC because of various cookies. And another human answered that it is not even possible because of iOS inner system organization

Comment: You could logout and relogin for every action.

Comment: It could be possible for simple tasks. But gmail login information is used for some websites such as youtube. So it is hard to religion each time

Comment: A WebService, which can store multiple GMail Logins?

Comment: Or using the imap protocol available to gmail users?

Comment: I almost didn't work with WebServices but as I understand it requires a separate server and to write some code to make this idea workable. So it is not very suitable for me.
I didn't worked with imap but I heard it has a limited functionality. I'll try it. Can you post any code or links about its usage?

Comment: do you need an info about OpenID?

Answer (score 1):

With libraries like [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) you can create multiple object managers to the same site and use different credentials. Read more about it in the API and examples. It is quite extensively supported.

If you are just looking to login to IMAP accounts then you can try libmailcore. [Read the getting started guide](http://libmailcore.com/) to see how to create an account and fetch data.

You can probably create multiple Account objects and work with those.